# Finding the quadratic coefficient of a quartic polynomial given other coefficients.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a question which I want to solve, taken from [this sample question paper](http://www.iitpk.com/pdf/GETSCHOLARS-a.pdf) for an exam I'm appearing for tommorow:

The product of two of the roots of $$x^4-11x^3+kx^2+269x-2001$$ is $-69$. Find $k$.

Let $a,b,c,d$ be the roots.
Then $a+b+c+d=11$
Also $ab+bc+cd+ac+bd+ad=k$
Also $abc+acd+bad+cbd=-269$
Finally $abcd=-2001$
Now should I find $k$?

Comment: WLG let $ab=-69$, then use that to solve those 4 equations

Comment: The product $abcd$ is $-2001$.

Comment: http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=36018

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the product of $a$ and $b$ is $-69$.

First, $cd = -2001 / -69 = 29$.

Then, $$ab(c+d) + cd (a+b) = ab(11-a-b) + cd(a+b)$$$$ = -759 + 69(a+b) + 29(a+b) = 98(a+b) - 759 = -269,$$ so $a+b = 490/98 = 5$.

You can solve $a+b = 5$ and $ab = -69$ with the quadratic formula to get $a,b$. You can get $c,d$ the same way.

Comment: Instead of the quadratic formula, for the last step you can also use $k = ab + cd + (a+b)(c+d)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* : $ab=-69\iff cd=\frac{-2001}{-69}=29$ . Replace then these products in the other equations and check to see if by any chance $c=\pm1$ and $d=\pm29$ might not be a solution, since $29$ is prime.